# Entity Framework 6 update with required complex property validation error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have been using Entity Framework for a couple years now and the Update process seems to always perplex me.  I have a Visual Studio MVC solution with 4 projects.  ( Web, Models, SharedContext and a Windows service)  The windows service (WS) is responsible for monitoring the database. The Web and WS projects both use the SharedContext for accessing the database.  So here goes.

It took me a while to figure that to enable lazy I need to add this to my WS constructor.

```
context = new SharedContext();
context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
```

Next I retrieve my requests by doing this.

```
var requests = context.Requests.Where(x => x.Status == FAFSpeachDB.Models.RequestStatus.approved &&
                        DateTime.Now >= x.PresentationDate
                        && !x.EvaluationEmailSent).ToList();
```

This gives me a list of the Entities that I am looking at.

Finally while looping through the list of requests I attempt to update the request object and save it to the DB.

```
request.EvaluationEmailSent = true;
context.SaveChanges();
```

When I do this I get an Entity Validation error telling me that the 'Invitation' property is required. (Which it is, but because lazy load is working I would expect the SavedChanges call to work with out a hitch.)  Okay so now here is the real crazy part.  When I make the call as shown below it works without an error.

```
int invitationId = request.Invitation.IdModel;
request.EvaluationEmailSent = true;
context.SaveChanges();
```

My only guess is that by adding a some line of code that access the invitation property it is setting the context in a state that allows it to updated.  Am I doing something wrong here? Or if I am not doing anything wrong why does just access the property remove the Entity Validation error.

Comment: Can you show us your model?

Comment: Is `Invitation` complex property or a navigation property to a different entity?

Comment: Is `EvaluationEmailSent` just a flat property, i.e. it doesn't cause side-effects in its setter? Furher, `LazyLoadingEnabled` and `ProxyCreationEnabled` are `true` by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set lazy loading to `true` which means nothing will be loaded until it's actually used. so, the `Invitation` property would not be loaded until you try to access it, as you did in your example.

Try adding `.Include("Invitation")` (or plural "Invitations") to your original query, so it looks like this:

```
var requests = context.Requests.Include("Invitation")
               .Where(x => x.Status == FAFSpeachDB.Models.RequestStatus.approved 
               && DateTime.Now >= x.PresentationDate
               && !x.EvaluationEmailSent)
               .ToList();
```